# Error 'no points in data' when using knnImpute in caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

To demonstrate this issue since I can't upload my data I've borrowed the code from http://mkseo.pe.kr/stats/?p=719 (many thanks to Minkoo for his site).

The only thing I've changed here is 'bagImpute' changed to 'knnImpute' to demonstrate the issue. I've omitted last couple of lines that are not relevant to this issue. Running this code results in

Error in nn2(old[, cols, drop = FALSE], new[, cols, drop = FALSE], k = k) : 
  no points in data!

```
library(caret)
library(doMC)  # For parallelism.

data(iris)
# 80% for training and 20% for verification.
# createDataPartition takes stratified samples,
# i.e., it takes the equal number of samples from each Species.
inTrain <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.8, list=FALSE)
training <- iris[inTrain, ]
verification <- iris[-inTrain, ]

# Make some data (incl. verification) missing on purpose.
fillInNa <- function(d) {
  naCount <- NROW(d) * 0.1
  for (i in sample(NROW(d), naCount)) {
    d[i, sample(4, 1)] <- NA
  }
  return(d)
}

training <- fillInNa(training)
verification <- fillInNa(verification)

# Because we have missing values across all columns, we need to
# use bagged trees. If just one column had NAs, we can use
# knnImpute which is faster. Also, note that preProcess is done
# only for training. For verification, we use the
# preProc generated from training.
preProc <- preProcess(method="knnImpute", training[, 1:4])
training[, 1:4] <- predict(preProc, training[, 1:4])
verification[, 1:4] <- predict(preProc, verification[, 1:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote here works for me:

```
> verification[, 1:4] <- predict(preProc, verification[, 1:4])
> head(verification)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
5    -1.0128842  0.03725657    -1.132276   -1.048478  setosa
7    -1.4933036  0.78647702    -1.344562   -1.206576  setosa
14   -1.8536182 -0.12129745    -1.512934   -1.470408  setosa
21   -0.5324648  0.78647702    -1.176189   -1.338492  setosa
23   -1.4933036  1.24036425    -1.569059   -1.338492  setosa
27   -1.0128842  0.78647702    -1.232313   -1.074660  setosa

R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RColorBrewer_1.0-5  knitr_1.6           magrittr_1.1.0      gtable_0.1.2        reshape2_1.4       
 [6] reshape_0.8.5       raster_2.2-31       sp_1.0-15           akima_0.5-11        randomForest_4.6-10
[11] earth_3.2-7         plotrix_3.5-7       plotmo_1.3-3        caret_6.0-30        lattice_0.20-29    
[16] dplyr_0.2           plyr_1.8.1          ggplot2_1.0.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1      BradleyTerry2_1.0-5 brglm_0.5-9         car_2.0-20          codetools_0.2-8    
 [6] colorspace_1.2-4    digest_0.6.4        evaluate_0.5.5      foreach_1.4.2       formatR_0.10       
[11] gtools_3.4.1        iterators_1.0.7     labeling_0.2        lme4_1.1-7          MASS_7.3-31        
[16] Matrix_1.1-3        minqa_1.2.3         munsell_0.4.2       nlme_3.1-117        nloptr_1.0.4       
[21] nnet_7.3-8          packrat_0.4.0.8     parallel_3.1.0      proto_0.3-10        Rcpp_0.11.2        
[26] scales_0.2.4        splines_3.1.0       stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: Strange. It doesn't work for me. I'm assuming you are on the latest version of caret and all its dependencies. If so, I'm at a loss here. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry. I runned your code while working on a project I started some time ago and I do not used latest R and caret version I edited the answer with my session info

Comment: Based on our testing, this is fixed in the just-released version of `caret` on CRAN